# Where to find WdRef dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, face-recognition

I can't find image files for WDRef dataset. Where to get it?

In [publication](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~chendong/JointBayesian/eccv_2012_bayesian.pdf) authors wrote:

> To address this issue, we introduce a new
>   dataset, Wide and Deep Reference dataset (WDRef), which is both wide (around
>   3,000 subjects) and deep (2,000+ subjects with over 15 images, 1,000+ subjects
>   with more than 40 images). To facilitate further research and evaluation on
>   supervised methods on the same test bed, we also share two kinds of extracted
>   low-level features of this dataset. The whole dataset can be downloaded from
>   our project website http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~chendong/JointBayesian/.

But, there are only LE and LBP features on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Only features are available for WDRef dataset.

Another large dataset is here:
http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/english/CASIA-WebFace-Database.html

Also on this webpage, it is confirmed that WDRef is feature only public.

Comment: the Link ist dead